# Why does script not recognize file extension?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My script

```
#!/bin/bash

cp *.ats /home/milenko/procmt

mycd() {
  cd /home/milenko/procmt
}

mycd

EXT=ats
for i in *; do
    if [ "${i}" != "${i%.${EXT}}" ];then
        ./tsmp -ascii i
    fi
done
```

But

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/Serra do Mel/MT06/meas_2016-07-13_20-22-00$ bash k1.sh


./tsmp: handling 1 files ************************************** total input channels: 1
the name of your file does not end with ats ... might crash soon

main (no rda) -> can not open i for input, exit


./tsmp: handling 1 files ************************************** total input channels: 1
the name of your file does not end with ats ... might crash soon

main (no rda) -> can not open i for input, exit
```

When I go to procmt directory and list files

```
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/procmt$ ls *.ats
262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_2048H.ats  262_V01_C00_R086_TEx_BL_4096H.ats  262_V01_C02_R000_THx_BL_2048H.ats
262_V01_C00_R000_TEx_BL_4096H.ats  262_V01_C01_R000_TEy_BL_2048H.ats  262_V01_C03_R000_THy_BL_2048H.ats
```

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: `./tsmp -ascii i` is not `./tsmp -ascii "$i"`; you aren't expanding the variable at all, so you're always giving it `i` as a filename. `i` is not a string that ends in `.ats`, so, well, there's your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly this should work for you:

```
dest='/home/milenko/procmt'

cp *.ats "$dest"

cd "$dest"

for i in *.ats; do
     ./tsmp -ascii "$i"
done
```

There is no need to loop through all files when you're only interested in `.ats` files. Your `mycd` function is just doing `cd` so you can avoid that as well.

Comment: Might `|| exit` on the `cd`, just as a showing-good-practices thing -- we wouldn't want to try to run a bunch of `./tsmp` commands if we failed to cd to `/home/milenko/procmt` for whatever reason.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes that's a good point but I think `cp` will fail before `cd` if user has permission issue for the given path.

Comment: @anubhava, good point -- though I note that we aren't exiting if the `cp` fails either. (Which might be fine -- maybe we want to process files already there even if there's nothing that matches the glob in the current working directory; by contrast, if the `cd` fails, I can't see a circumstance in which it would be defensibly correct to continue).